# How to dynamically generate Bing/Google map with multiple pinpoints?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, bing-maps

> **What I have?**

I have Set of multiple `LAT-LONG` values in the *Database*.
Every `LAT-LONG` value is associated with a `STATUS`.

> **What I need?**

I need to generate ***Bing Map***, load the map with all available `LAT-LONG` values and show them as **PINPOINTS**. Pinpoint color must be different based on the `STATUS` for corresponding `LAT-LONG` value.

And, the most important part is I need to generate everything on the fly (i.e. at runtime using **Windows Service**) and then save it as PDF somewhere.

Basically, the Windows Service will generate the PDF, save it somewhere and email it to relevant people.

> **So, basically, these are my 3 questions:**

1. Is it even possible?
2. If yes, what is the correct approach to proceed with.
3. If no, can you think of any alternative solution or any other ideas?

**Technologies:** *.NET 4.0, C#*

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to generate a static map in order to integrate it in a PDF file.

In order to do so, I will recommend to use the Bing Maps Imagery REST Service, see the MSDN for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Also, the service (like any Maps REST service) does not support custom pushpin so you will have to add our own logic after retrieving the image and draw the element using GDI and use the appropriate image depending on the values of the properties on your elements.

So, to bring answers to your questions:

1. Yes it is possible. Not natively in your case.
2. The best approach would be to call the REST imagery service and draw your elements on top the retrieved map imagery.
3. An alternative solution would be to provide an interactive map but you won't be able to integrate it in a PDF file so it's really changing what you can do.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, Only problem with that is: REST imagery puts a limit on how many PUSHPINS can be used (i.e. it only allows me to create a map with max 100 pushpins). I need to have more than that. Any ideas? Check pp under Map Parameters section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Comment: There is two limitations that apply in your use case: 1: the number of pushpin is limited ; 2: the image used for pushpin are limited to those supported. 
That's why I recommend to add your own logic to be able to draw (on your server side) your own element on top of the retrieved image.

Comment: Could you please explain on what do you mean by "Draw on top of retrieved element". How do I draw 1000s of pushpins mapped properly on top of a map? Any example or sample?